# What changes in New Game+?

Tags: everything

Shortly after unlocking the ability to join with *Everything*, I received a notification saying I had unlocked the option to play New Game+. Seeing as *Everything* doesn't really have an ending or linear story, I'm a bit confused what this mode would entail.

What changes when playing New Game Plus? Do you keep all your collected things and abilities?

Comment: Can I just say, this was hilarious to see in the question list. "What changes in New Game+? [tag:everything]."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The tutorial is skipped, you start with all abilities and the gate unlocked. That's about it

reply on steam community discussion by "Hato1 ;)" for everything:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/582270/discussions/0/1318836262653865041/